# AS2 Trigger onRelease event

Tags: actionscript, triggers, movieclip, actionscript-2

Hey all, i have a movieclip with an onRelease event. Is there anyway i can trigger this event in code? without clicking the movie clip?

Answer (score 1):

if you set onRelease to a function then you can just call that function on the MovieClip

```
mc.onRelease = function(){
    trace('mc.onRelease called');
}
mc.onRelease();
```